# Multiple callback cause ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, android, concurrency, callback

I am having a for loop that call a callback for each object, each will do some modification to the same SharedPreference data. How do I prevent them from modifying the data (while another is reading/modifying it)?

```
ArrayList<Object> arrayList = ... //initialize with data
for(Object i: arraylist){
    Callback cb = new Callback(){
        @Override
        public void onResult(String info, float v)
        {
           //modify the data in SharedPreference (not in the arraylist)
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You can use a CopyOnWriteArrayList which supports concurrency.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

Comment: The modifications happen to data in SharedPreference, the arrayList remains the same the whole time

Comment: I don't understand your code. What is the loop supposed to do? In your sample you just create a new callback at each iteration but it's not stored or call by anything. Plus if you're modifying the same Shared preference entry, it means the last value stored is the one from the last entry of your array. So what's the point of the loop? There is either something wrong in your implementation or you need to provide more information, or both.